# How to prove $\frac{3!}{2(n+3)}= \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \frac{ n\choose r}{{r+3}\choose r}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove  $$\frac{3!}{2(n+3)}= \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \frac{ n\choose r}{{r+3}\choose r}$$?

I'm really not getting any nerve to prove this. Can anyone help me in deducing this. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,
$$ \binom{r+3}{r} = \binom{r+3}{3} = \frac{1}{3!}(r+1)(r+2)(r+3). $$
Now, we have the identity
$$ \frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}, $$
which follows from the definition of the binomial coefficient. Applying this three times, we have
$$ \frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)} \binom{n}{r} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\binom{n+3}{r+3}. $$
The sum we now have to evaluate is
$$ S =\sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r \binom{n+3}{r+3} = -\sum_{s=3}^{n+3} (-1)^s \binom{n+3}{s}. $$
However, Euler showed that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} = 0 $$
(Look at $(1-1)^m$ with the binomial theorem.); in our case, this implies that
$$ S= -\sum_{s=3}^{n+3} (-1)^s \binom{n+3}{s}-\sum_{s=0}^{2} (-1)^s \binom{n+3}{s}+\sum_{s=0}^{2} (-1)^s \binom{n+3}{s} = \sum_{s=0}^{2} (-1)^s \binom{n+3}{s}, $$
and this evaluates to
$$ \sum_{s=0}^{2} (-1)^s \binom{n+3}{s} = 1-(n+3)+\frac{1}{2}(n+3)(n+2)=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2). $$

Therefore the whole lot is
$$ \frac{3!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} = \frac{3!}{2(n+3)}, $$
as required.

Comment: Could you tell, please, how you've written $\binom{r+3}{r} = \binom{r+3}{3}$, after all, $r$ ranges from $0$ to $n$?

Comment: For any $m$ and $k$, it is true that $\binom{m}{k}=\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}=\binom{m}{m-k}$.